# Should the tap area be visible to users?

Tags: gui-design, human-interface-guideline, mobile-first

I am looking to find what the best practice is for tap areas, or tap targets.

[There is a lot of discussion as to what is the best size to have as a minimum tap area.](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1085)

There is also a some documentation which seems a sensible rule [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/SizeTapTargetsAppropriately).

Whilst it is obvious to me that the above rules and best practice has a minimum tap area - my question is this...

Is there a need to have the minimum tap area represented as a visual? For example - if a button is meant to be a minimum of 44 points high, should the visual button be 44 points high? Or can the tap area be take the 44 points, and the button be smaller - providing that nothing is intruding on its space?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I'm in favor of migrating your question to UX but I'm not one of the web people here so I'll wait to see if they agree with me or want to answer here.

Comment: I'd have to agree with @Ryan, this is more of a UX designer, rather than graphic designer, question. I vote to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Provide a clear implied area

Depending on the visual complexity of your view, visible targets can be a useful way of clarifying actions for the user. But even in info-dense applications, it's not always necessary.

A very good example is the ubiquitous tabbed navigation pattern. In this example from Google's Material Design specification, the user has a fairly clear expectation about where the target area lies.

[image: Material Design tabbed navigation]

Another area where it's useful to avoid visualizing the full target is with tertiary actions (of which there can be many in modern web apps). The cancel button in this modal pattern is one example.

[image: Simple sign in modal with "ghost button" style cancel action]